# How can I receive data from UHF RFID reader's USB port to my raspberrypi controller

Tags: python, pi-2, usb, serial, rfid

I am new to raspberry pi, currently we want to develop gate control with open/close boom-barrier so we are using an UHF RFID reader and a raspberry pi.  I bought a RFID reader that has a USB connector (PC com) interface and other interface are wiegand d0,d1 and other +12V,gnd, trigger point. How can I receive RFID tag data from reader to my raspberry pi through the RFID reader's USB interface which I connected to my raspberry pi? I want to use raspberry pi as controller so I can send RFID tag id/data to my server to check whether it is authenticated or not and insert in my database. I need help. Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @jsotola no this live project for industry, apartment, society and i want to develop without pc only using raspberrypi

Comment: @jsotola only i want to know can i get data from usb serial port in raspberry pi ? if it is possible to get data from usb PC COM port. then next step i will execute.

Comment: you are not understanding my comment ..... i do not know what kind of an RFID reader you have ..... it has a USB cable so it is possible that it emulates a keyboard ....... plug the RFID reader into a computer, open a text editor so that you can see keypresses .... then scan a tag .... if it is a keyboard emulator, then you will see the tag number in the text editor window

Comment: better still, update your question with information about the RFID reader